# How to avoid copy and paste in a single T-SQL statement

Tags: t-sql

There is some new feature of SQL, I think that it was intruduced in 2005 that I never used. I can't remember what it was called, but I recall reading about it. It was an acronym similar to CT_ or something....

It was used to avoid reproducing the same code within a single SQL, for readability and (I assume) for performance reasons--because the common code would only be evaluated once.

What was it called? I am having a bit of trouble trying to find it and thought someone could easily tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) or CTE. It's especially useful for [recursive queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).